# Compute percentile for pandas dataframe row based on previous years data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
datetime       JD      YEAR    VAL 
2000-01-01      1      2000    0.5
2000-01-02      2      2000    1.2
2000-01-03      3      2000    2.1
2000-01-04      4      2000    3.4 
2000-01-05      5      2000    4.6
2000-01-06      6      2000    6.8
2000-01-07      7      2000    7.2
2000-01-08      8      2000    0.2
2000-01-09      9      2000    0.9
...
2010-12-31      365    2014    4.1
```

The first year is 2000 and last year is 2010. There are no leap years (i.e. no row corresponding to Feb 29th), datetime is the index column.

I would like to compute a new dataframe, stretching from Jan 1st 2010 to Dec 31st 2010. I would like it to contains a column which computes the percentile of Jan 1st 2010 value (VAL) in the array composed of 10 values (Jan 1st 2000, Jan 1st 2001...Jan 1st 2009). Similarly, Jan 2nd 2010 is compared against Jan 2nd from previous years....

```
lyr = df.YEAR.max() # last year i.e. 2010
cdf = df[df.YEAR == lyr]# Latest year dataframe
pdf = df[df.index.year < lyr] # Previous years dataframe

pdf.groupby('JD')['VAL']
stats.percentileofscore(pdf['VAL'], cdf['VAL'])
```

However, I am not sure how to get the code to work. The groupby only returns group whereas I need a list of values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set up with a small sample dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'jd':  np.tile([1,2],3),
                    'yr':  np.repeat([2008,2009,2010],2),
                    'val': np.random.randn(6) })
```

Then it's just one line:

```
df['pctile'] = df.groupby('jd')['val'].rank(pct=True)
```

Here's the output, sorted with `sort_values(['jd','val'])`

```
   jd       val    yr    pctile
4   1 -0.720589  2010  0.333333
0   1  0.471435  2008  0.666667
2   1  1.432707  2009  1.000000
1   2 -1.190976  2008  0.333333
3   2 -0.312652  2009  0.666667
5   2  0.887163  2010  1.000000
```

Comment: .rank(pct=True) does not return the real percentiles. It's just ranking the values but not using the same logic when calculating percentiles. So this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @bbennett36  I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying.  Rank & percentile ought to at least share the same sort ordering.  What do you think are the correct percentile values in this example?  Please feel free to add your own answer here if you have a better or more correct way to do it.

Comment: I guess the answer isn't technically incorrect but it might be useful to add that this is the [nearest-rank method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) to calculate percentiles.

However, the 'quantile' function in pandas and the default method for numpy in the 'linear interpolation' method. 

So what happened was I used the rank method to calculate percentiles for one dataset but quantiles for the same data and they weren't matching up because they don't use the same method. Also, the rank method won't always return the median at the 50th rank which is what I was comparing against.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804120/how-do-i-get-the-percentile-for-a-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe

I'm looking for the 'linear interpolation' percentile basically. Not the ranked version. Since OP didn't specify his method I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @bbennett36  thanks, and it is your right to downvote so do it if you think it's fair, but asking the specific question like you are doing is the better way IMO.  +1 on the question, for karma  ;-)