# Find percentile of a column called mag(earthquake magnitue)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, percentile

How could I approach to find 95th percentile of a column data?
The question is:
FInd the 95th percentile of earthquake magnitude in Japan using the magType of 'mb'.

I am able to filter Magtype 'mb', but how could I find the percentile?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data/parsed.csv', usecols=['time', 'title', 'place',
            'magType', 'mag', 'alert','tsunami'])
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample records of the dataframe. df.head(20)

Comment: see if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804120/how-do-i-get-the-percentile-for-a-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581893/pandas-find-percentile-stats-of-a-given-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: find percentile stats of a given column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581893/pandas-find-percentile-stats-of-a-given-column)

Answer (score 0):

```
df_place = df.groupby(["parsed_place"])
df_japan  = df_place.get_group("Japan")
df_japan.tail(2)
df_japan.quantile(0.95)
```

Comment: A good answer should include motivation for *why* the code provided works, not just *what* the code is.