# Calculate Percentile from CDF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cdf

I have calculated cdf for a data set in pandas df and want to determine the respective percentile from the cdf chart.
code for cdf:

```
def cdf(x):
    df_1=pmf(x)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df1['pmf'] = df_1['pmf'].sort_index()
    df1['x'] = df_1['x']
    df1['cdf'] = np.cumsum(df1['pmf'])
    return df1
```

This is the generated cdf df:
[image]

Now i want to write a simple logic to fetch the "x" data corresponding to a cdf for determining percentile.
Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941436/compute-percentile-for-pandas-dataframe-row-based-on-previous-years-data
Visit this link this might be helpful

Comment: the link is very confusing kind of like expert debate

Comment: @AbhishekKumar : Did you get an answer for this? Its always advised to either accept a given answer if it met your requirements, or you can answer your own question so that users searching for the same/similar problems has an answer to their problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: one more option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309977/68998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it as below(use df name in place of df below):

```
df.loc[df['cdf'] == 0.999083, 'x']
```

output:

```
12.375
```